# Join из двух больших таблиц, как ускорить?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select, join

Есть таблица с товарами (item) и таблица с цветами товаров (item_color). Связи "один товар к нескольким цветам". Таблицы большие, item - 1,5 млн строк, item_color 2,5 млн. Тип - InnoDB.

На странице интернет-магазина необходимо вывести фильтры по цветам, размерам товаров. Всего фильтров - 6 штук. Для этого использую подобные запросы:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_color.id_color FROM item_color 
JOIN item ON item.id = item_color.id_item 
AND item.enabled=1 
AND item.id_category BETWEEN 10100000 AND 10199999
```

Сервер: 2 ядра, 4Гб ОЗУ. Запрос выполняется 6-8 секунд.

Индексы таблицы Item:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `c` (`id_category`),
KEY `e` (`enabled`),
KEY `ce` (`id_category`,`enabled`),
KEY `iec` (`id`,`enabled`,`id_category`),
KEY `cei` (`id_category`,`enabled`,`id`)
```

Индексы таблицы Item_color:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `ic` (`id_item`,`id_color`),
KEY `ci` (`id_color`,`id_item`),
KEY `i` (`id_item`)
```

Explain:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оптимизировать запрос? 
Может быть я выбрал неверный подход в построении фильтров?

Comment: Для начала удалите индекс `e`. Индексы с такой селективностью только замедляют работу. остальные индексы вообще то же не помешало бы пересмотреть. например зачем вам одновременно `ic` и `ci` во второй таблице. явно достаточно `ci`. И кстати что у вас за поле `id` в той таблице. В связующих таблицах собственное поле id в 95% случаев не нужно. Вот `ci` в этой таблице подходит на роль первичного ключа

Comment: И да, запрос какой то искусственный "дай мне уникальные цвета товаров в категориях в диапазоне таком то". просто distinct сильно портит запрос. А применимость результатов запроса на нуле

Comment: Конкретно для этого запроса идеальным наверное был бы `ce` с полями наоборот. но это для данного, конкретного, очень искусственного, запроса

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно получить список цветов в категории по опубликованным товарам, чтобы вывести список цветов в фильтр. Думаю, при таком количестве товаров это и правда займет много времени, вне зависимости от индексов.

Попробуйте разбить запрос на несколько:

1. Получить id опубликованных товаров в категории (`select id from item where ...`).
2. По id товаров получить уникальные цвета (`select distinct id_color from iitem_color where id_item in (...)`).

Попробуйте разобраться со скоростью этих запросов сначала. Если будет быстрее, то можно уже думать об оптимизации индексов под join, или так и оставить получение данных несколькими запросами.

Если быстрее не получится, то можно тогда закешировать результат для категории, например, на сутки. Тогда лишь один раз в сутки посетитель будет ждать 8 секунд (для одной категории). Или можно обновлять кеш по cron, чтобы никто не ждал.

Или, на крайний случай, просто в фильтре выводите список всех имеющихся цветов, вне зависимости от того, есть такие товары или нет.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, разделил запрос на два. Первый выполняется за 0,1-0,2 сек в зависимости от кол-ва товаров в категории. Второй запрос с IN (ids) выполняется за 0,5 сек (при 40к товаров в категории) и 4 сек (при 250к товаров в категории). Это в принципе терпимо, но таких фильтров 5. Суммарное время выполнения будет в районе 20-25 сек. Сейчас попробую с индексами поэкспериментировать. Если не получится, то как решение: для "тяжелых" категорий буду просто выводить в фильтре все цвета, все размеры и т.п.

Comment: Попробуйте все-таки для тяжелых категорий реализовать кеширование. Это будет хороший компромисс.

Comment: @librown если вам помог ответ, пожалуйста, примите его.

Answer (score 0):

С MySql не работал, поэтому дам общие советы:

Для начала оцени селективность индекса. Я вижу очень много индексов.

Возможно, на некоторые колонки индексы не нужны и проще просканировать таблицу целиком.

Попробуй вынести

```
item.enabled=1 
AND item.id_category BETWEEN 10100000 AND 10199999
```

в WHERE и растравить в порядке наибольшей вероятности попадания в условие(Что бы лишний раз не просматривать другие условия)

Далее, что я вижу, это слабый ПК. Вполне вероятно, что узкое место в конфигурации пк, так как я не вижу ничего криминального в самом запросе.

Answer (score 0):

План показывает, что для первой таблицы выбран индекс e. И по нему перебираются все 106113 активных записей. Укажите запросу через [FORCE INDEX](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/select.html) (USE INDEX) использовать другой ключ (я бы поставил "с" - по категории)

Составные ключи с полем enabled, как я думаю, имеют смысл лишь при большой доле отключенных записей. Но в таком случае лучше их убрать из оперативных таблиц/БД и вынести в архив.